# How to retrieve a specific column from a table using hibernate lucene search?

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I need to retrieve a specific column using an Hibernate Search query. I tried with projections but that didn't work out. Please help me to achieve this, any advice or suggestion will be appreciated.
Here is my query:

```
     FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
     QueryBuilder b = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Company.class).get();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery =
            b.keyword()
                .onFields("company_name","city")
                .matching("search keyword here!")
                .createQuery();
        org.hibernate.Query fullTextQuery=fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery).setProjection().setProperties("company_name");       
        List result = fullTextQuery.list();
```

Comment: You should show us the projections query if you want us to possibly suggest why that didn't work. Also to begin with, it might be useful to use a "new org.apache.lucene.search.MatchAllDocsQuery()" as luceneQuery, and see what gets projected.

Comment: Thnaks for your info sanne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use projections.
But before that you must store that column value using store=Store.yes

```
@Field(store=Store.YES)
private String name;
```

In the program, you can use projection

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Employee.class).get();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("name").matching(name).createQuery();
org.hibernate.search.FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Employee.class);
fullTextQuery.setProjection("name");

List list = fullTextQuery.list();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer @vrb